# Why flow doesn't understand `export default`

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Two instances of code:

```
const obj = {}
export default obj


export default obj = {}
```

[Flow](https://flow.org/en/) gives an error on the second

> Cannot resolve name `obj`

Is there something wrong with the code in second place? It works just fine, but flow warns me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const obj = {
    // property goes here
}
export default obj
```

or,

```
export default {
   // property goes here
 }
```

or

```
let obj;
export default obj =  {
  // property goes here
}
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: so `export default obj = {}` isn't correct? I use obj below `expart default` and it works

Comment: Sorry, `export default obj = {}` is a valid. But you've to declare `obj` first. I've updated the answer. But you can't do  `export default const obj = {}`. It is not possible to use `var`, `let` or `const` with `export default`.

Comment: Yes! The variable is not declared. You said it is working although. Give a try  with 'strict' mode.